How can I remove fusion chart trail water mark in angular?
<fusioncharts class="fusion_chart" [dataSource]="dataSource">   </fusioncharts>

I have tried css to hide this but it wont work
g[class$="creditgroup"] {
  display: none !important;
}
g[class^="raphael-group-"][class`your text`$="-creditgroup"] {
  display: none !important;
}
svg > g[class^="raphael-group-"] > text {
  display: none;
}
[pointer-events="bounding-box"] {
  display: none;
}
svg > g[class^="raphael-group-"] g {
  fill: none !important;
}


::ng-deep
  .fusion_chart 
  #container-2
  #chartobject-2
  #raphael-paper-4
  > g[class^="raphael-group-"] {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}

::ng-deep
  .fusion_chart
  #container-2
  #chartobject-2
  #raphael-paper-4
  > g[class$="messageGroup"] {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
::ng-deep
  .fusion_chart
  #container-2
  #chartobject-2
  #raphael-paper-4
  > g[class$="parentgroup"] {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

It works for angular by using - (::ng-deep)

Thanks lots, Its Working. I sufferd because of this issue finaly got solution
